# CalledFromWrongThreadException: while Changing View color (Android)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to change the background color of a `View` which acts as a square that ticks alongside other sound samples.

When I go to run it, it comes up with the error:

> ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Can anyone please provide a solution?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act2);

    final View square = (View)findViewById(R.id.rec);

    tone = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (sound[0] % 4 != 0) {
                s2.start();
                sound[0] += 1;
                square.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
            } else {
                s2.start();
                sound[0] = 1;
                square.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
            }
        }
    };

}
```

The sound part of the code works fine, it's just when I try to use `View`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your UI related code to UI thread instead. You can not update ui form TimerTask

Code:

```
tone = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (sound[0] % 4 != 0) {
            s2.start();
            sound[0] += 1;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
                 public void run() {
                    square.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

void run method in timer task is on a new thread and not UI thread. You cannot setBackgroundColor in this thread. You should do it in UI thread as follows.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
             public void run() {
                square.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
            }
        });
```